# How do I get a specific pull request on my machine?

Tags: git, github

Someone sent me a pull request. Before I merge it, I want to look at the changes on my machine. How do I do that?

Comment: I have seen lots of other more complex answers to this question. I found an answer I liked a lot better, so I'm putting it on stackoverflow so I can find it again. Maybe it will help you, too?

Comment: Doesn't the email that GitHuv sends you include this information?

Comment: The email I got recently looked like this: `git pull https://github.com/USER/PROJECT BRANCH`, which is useful but different. Maybe there's something I'm missing.

Answer (score 27):

From http://community.elgg.org/pages/view/1123557/how-to-check-out-a-pull-request-for-testing

For pull request #123:

```
git fetch origin pull/123/head:pr-123
git checkout pr-123
```

Comment: Wow, how did I not know this yet? o.O Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks, and how do I update it after pull request code was updated, force-pushed?