# How can I check out a GitHub pull request with git?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-checkout

I'd like to check out a previously created pull request (created via GitHub web interface). I searched and found different places where a refs/pull or refs/pull/pr

But when I add `fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*` to the git config file and do a git fetch

What I'm doing wrong? Should GitHub create automatically the pull/xyz stuff, or do I have to configure something?

Comment: What does the complete remote section of your config file look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I fetch an unmerged pull request for a branch I don't own?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743514/how-can-i-fetch-an-unmerged-pull-request-for-a-branch-i-dont-own)

Comment: possible duplicate of [github clone from pull request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947789/github-clone-from-pull-request)

Comment: I ended up on this question, but I actually needed https://stackoverflow.com/q/1783405/2413303

Comment: The second paragraph is not a complete sentence. "But when I add ... and do a git fetch" - when you do these things *what* happens?

Answer (score 858, accepted):

To fetch a remote PR into your local repo,

```
git fetch origin pull/$ID/head:$BRANCHNAME
```

where `$ID` is the pull request id and `$BRANCHNAME` is the name of the new branch that you want to create. Once you have created the branch, then simply

```
git checkout $BRANCHNAME
```

For instance, let's imagine you want to checkout pull request #2 from the origin main branch:

```
git fetch origin pull/2/head:MASTER
```

See the [official GitHub documentation](https://help.github.com/en/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally) for more.

Comment: I used this to fetch a pr from an upstream repo into my local forked repo, you can replace origin with upstream as well.

Comment: My command ended up looking like `git fetch origin pull/1/head:githubusername` , not what I was expecting

Comment: @Antoine `BRANCHNAME` is whatever you want to name the branch. I'm guessing you tried to use a name that already existed (e.g. `master`) and that didn't work, so you tried your username, which did work, because their was no branch with that name. Perhaps I misunderstand what you were saying.

Comment: It may be the case that you configured your local repo the way that `origin` points to your fork and `upstream` – to the original repository (following https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork, for instance). Make sure to change `origin` to `upstream` in the mentioned command, if you want to fetch pull request from the original repo.

Comment: I was trying to fetch including the "#" symbol in the ID, as highlighted in GitHubs documentation, as in `pull/#1/head:branch`. Only the number must go in, so `pull/1/head/branch`.

Comment: Just one question please, how to fetch new-coming commits to this local-created branch?

Comment: Was able to solve the issue using the [GitHub Documentation link](https://help.github.com/en/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally) posted by @timbo

Comment: i suggest as an improvement to this post an example with content, e.g., if the pull request is #37 and the new branch I want to create is called "regressionFixes", then "git fetch origin pull/37/head:regressionFixes"

And, another would be making it all one command (because it's easy to forget to switch branches); i.e., with above example: "git fetch origin pull/37/head:regressionFixes && git checkout regressionFixes"

Comment: Also note that "head" needs to be in small letters, not the usual caps HEAD.

Comment: you can also omit branch name and then do `git checkout FETCH_HEAD`

Comment: How does one pull PR updates if the author commits changes to the same PR?

Comment: Where are the changes? `git status` shows none of the changes in the PR, and `git pull` says everything is up to date.

Answer (score 204):

This will fetch without you having to name a branch:

```
git pull origin pull/939/head
```

[How do I get a specific pull request on my machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15397059/#32447815)

Comment: Note that if you do this while on your master branch, for example, it will commit directly into this branch. If you'd like to bring the pull request into a separate branch for staging, try @timbo's answer.

Comment: This also works if you later want to pull changes from the pull request into your local branch.

Comment: I was looking for this only, as I need to pull others code to review and I don't want to switch to a new branch

Answer (score 112):

I prefer to fetch and checkout *without creating a local branch* and to be in **HEAD detached state**. It allows me quickly to check the pull request without polluting my local machine with unnecessary local branches.

```
git fetch upstream pull/ID/head && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

where `ID` is a pull request ID and `upstream` where is original pull request has been created (it could be `origin`, for example).

Comment: I like this solution. One of the benefits is that if the PR is updated with more commits, then you can just run this again and it'll pull in the new commit(s).

Comment: Voted! No need for a local branch and can update from remote easily.

Comment: @JamesRao thanks, no local branch is the best part!

Comment: Thanks, is it true, I guess, that before git-gc, and even after `checkout` or `switch` to the original branch, there may still be some unconnected commits in the local repository?

Answer (score 69):

[That gist](https://gist.github.com/piscisaureus/3342247) does describe what happend when you do a git fetch:

> Obviously, change the github url to match your project's URL. It ends up looking like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:joyent/node.git
    fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Note the order of `fetch` refspecs, as suggested in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567846/how-can-i-check-out-a-github-pull-request-with-git/27567939?noredirect=1#comment130160009_27567939) by [crashneb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5844631/crashneb), in his [own's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40828472/6309).

If not, meaning if you don't have the  right order because of a:

> ```
> git config --add remote.origin.fetch "+refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*" ...
> ```
>
> and then trusted the PR-checkout to naturally setup the new local branch with something like `git switch pr/1` -- then you might have trouble should the PR get updated and you want to just `git pull` it again.
> The `branch.pr/1.merge` config value will not be correct.

---

> Now fetch all the pull requests:
>
> ```
> $ git fetch origin
> From github.com:joyent/node
>  * [new ref]         refs/pull/1000/head -> origin/pr/1000
>  * [new ref]         refs/pull/1002/head -> origin/pr/1002
>  * [new ref]         refs/pull/1004/head -> origin/pr/1004
>  * [new ref]         refs/pull/1009/head -> origin/pr/1009
> ...
> ```
>
> To check out a particular pull request:
>
> ```
> $ git checkout pr/999
> Branch pr/999 set up to track remote branch pr/999 from origin.
> Switched to a new branch 'pr/999'
> ```

You have various scripts listed in [issues 259](https://github.com/tj/git-extras/issues/259) to automate that task.
The **[git-extras](https://github.com/tj/git-extras)** project proposes the command `git-pr` (implemented in [PR 262](https://github.com/tj/git-extras/pull/262))

### `git-pr`(1) -- Checks out a pull request locally

> #### SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> git-pr <number> [<remote>]
> git-pr clean
> ```
>
> #### DESCRIPTION
>
> Creates a local branch based on a GitHub pull request number, and switch to that branch afterwards.
>
> The name of the remote to fetch from. Defaults to `origin`.
>
> #### EXAMPLES
>
> This checks out the pull request `226` from `origin`:
>
> ```
> $ git pr 226
>
> remote: Counting objects: 12, done.
> remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
> remote: Total 12 (delta 3), reused 9 (delta 3)
> Unpacking objects: 100% (12/12), done.
> From https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras
>   * [new ref] refs/pull/226/head -> pr/226
> Switched to branch 'pr/226'
> ```

Comment: I was not aware of the `git-extras` project, thanks for mentioning it! − See also this other SO answer [How do I checkout a PR from a fork?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62432946/9164010) where I proposed a similar command `git prw` that additionally *sets the upstream branch* (so the branch so obtained is not a "read-only" branch).

Comment: If you adjusted your config as prescribed by this answer, perhaps with something like `git config --add remote.origin.fetch "+refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*"` ...  and then trusted the PR-checkout to naturally setup the new local branch with something like `git checkout pr/1` -- then you will have trouble trying to just `git pull` it again to get PR updates.  The `branch.pr/1.merge` config value will not be correct.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40828472/5844631) for how to address that issue.

Comment: @CrashNeb Thank you for your feedback. I have edited the answer to include your comment for more visibility.

Answer (score 52):

The Github CLI [`gh`](https://cli.github.com) allows you to checkout a pull request's branch locally by its id ([doc](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_checkout))

```bash
gh pr checkout 2267
```

This allows pushing changes back to the fork as well with a simple `git push` if the PR submitter has given you [edit rights to their fork](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/allowing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork).

Answer (score 29):

If you are using Github.com, go to "Pull requests", click on the relevant pull request, and then click on the "command line instructions" link:
[image: command line instructions at Github.com]

Comment: Say, is there actually a way - when you are looking at github.com I mean - to download the new/changed files, of the PR?  So, when you are looking at a repo on github, you can click the handy "download as a zip" button, or indeed, you can, quite simply, click through and just look at each (entire) file of the project.  For PR, I can't see how to, simply, click through to "look at the file" - know what I mean?  Am I missing something?  Cheers!

Comment: @Fattie Yes. You simply click yourself through to your contributor's repository (you can pick any state of their repository, the latest or any other commit) and then use the *↓ Code* ➜ *Download ZIP* feature on the repository's main page.

Answer (score 22):

Referencing Steven Penny's answer, it's best to create a test branch and test the PR. So here's what you would do.

1. Create a test branch to merge the PR into locally. Assuming you're on the master branch:

`git checkout -b test`

2. Get the PR changes into the test branch

`git pull origin pull/939/head:test`

Now, you can safely test the changes on this local test branch (in this case, named *test*) and once you're satisfied, can merge it as usual from GitHub.

Comment: I'd go even one better - I would create a worktree, set it to a new `test` branch and   THEN pull in the PR - that way I don't need about restoring branches locally when done; I just dispose of the worktree. In fact I NEVER just `checkout -b` anymore - I always create a worktree and then branch. Disk is cheap. Of course, I have a script that does this; I don't type all the command needed individually.

Answer (score 12):

For Bitbucket, you need replace the word `pull` to `pull-requests`.

First, you can confirm the pull request URL style by `git ls-remote origin` command.

```
$ git ls-remote origin |grep pull
f3f40f2ca9509368c959b0b13729dc0ae2fbf2ae    refs/pull-requests/1503/from
da4666bd91eabcc6f2c214e0bbd99d543d94767e    refs/pull-requests/1503/merge
...
```

As you can see, it is `refs/pull-requests/1503/from` instead of `refs/pull/1503/from`

Then you can use the commands of any of the answers.

Answer (score 11):

The problem with some of options above, is that if someone pushes more commits to the PR after opening the PR, they won't give you the most updated version.
For me what worked best is - go to the PR, and press 'Commits', scroll to the *bottom* to see the most recent commit hash
[image]
and then simply use git checkout, i.e.

`git checkout <commit number>`

in the above example

`git checkout 0ba1a50`

Comment: I hit exactly this problem with the `git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME` approach mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30584951/659732. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 11):

You can use `git config` command to write a new rule to `.git/config` to fetch pull requests from the repository:

```
$ git config --local --add remote.origin.fetch '+refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*'
```

And then just:

```
$ git fetch origin
Fetching origin
remote: Counting objects: 4, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 2), reused 4 (delta 2), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
From https://github.com/container-images/memcached
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/2/head -> origin/pr/2
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/3/head -> origin/pr/3
```

Comment: What about pushing it back upstream for updates?

Answer (score 8):

If you're following the "github fork" workflow, where you create a fork and add the remote upstream repo:

```
14:47 $ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:<yourname>/<repo_name>.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:<yourname>/<repo_name>.git (push)
upstream        git@github.com:<repo_owrer>/<repo_name>.git (fetch)
upstream        git@github.com:<repo_owner>/<repo_name>.git (push)
```

to pull into your current branch your command would look like:

```
git pull upstream pull/<pull_request_number>/head
```

to pull into a new branch the code would look like:

```
git fetch upstream pull/<pull_request_number>/head:newbranch
```

Answer (score 8):

Although most of the answers on this thread work, I prefer to fetch a  pull request in a new branch and do a soft reset to an old commit (moves the PR changes to the staging area), this allows me to test the PR changes as well as see the difference in my IDE.

```
git fetch origin pull/<PR-id>/head:<BRANCH_NAME>
git checkout BRANCH_NAME
```

and then do a soft reset to a old commit (see list of commits using `git log`)

```
git reset --soft <hash_of_old_commit>
```

e.g

```bash
git fetch origin pull/65/head:test-branch 
git checkout test-branch
git log # press 'q' to exit
git reset --soft 7d7fe166cd878ed70c559c4e98faf2323532
```

Running the above command will pull the changes of the PR and show them in your IDE version and they won't be committed and you can see the difference in your staging area (as if those changes were made locally.)

Ref: [Github docs reference](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally)

Answer (score 6):

I'm using hub, a tool from github: https://github.com/github/hub

With hub checking out a pull request locally is kinda easy:

```
hub checkout https://github.com/owner/repo/pull/1234
or
hub pr checkout 1234
```

Answer (score 4):

I accidentally ended up writing almost the same as provided by git-extras. So if you prefer a single custom command instead of installing a bunch of other extra commands, just place [this `git-pr` file](https://gist.github.com/jhnns/d654d9d6da6d3b749986) somewhere in your `$PATH` and then you can just write:

```
git pr 42
// or
git pr upstream 42
// or
git pr https://github.com/peerigon/phridge/pull/1
```

Answer (score 4):

Get the remote PR branch into local branch:

`git fetch origin ‘remote_branch’:‘local_branch_name’`

Set the upstream of local branch to remote branch.

`git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/PR_Branch_Name local_branch`

When you want to push the local changes to PR branch again

`git push origin HEAD:remote_PR_Branch_name`

Comment: This should note that on Github, you can't actually edit the PR and push it back. The remote refs/pull/ namespace is [read-only](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally#modifying-an-inactive-pull-request-locally).

Answer (score 4):

With newer versions of Git:

`git fetch origin refs/pull-requests/<id>/from:<localbranchname>`

Answer (score 2):

To quickly check PR on your local, open it and check the branch name from which PR is created.

[image]
As we can see in the red line above name of branch is 'CLUPET-173-glrr-apis'
use below command to quickly see the code in the PR/Branch

```
git checkout origin/CLUPET-173-glrr-apis
```

Now this code on your local would run as detached head mode.

To **stop** all PR code viewing and to go back to your previous branch

```
git switch -
```

In case you want to move PR(plus any new local changes you made after fetching PR) to a new local branch use below command

```
git switch -c myNewLocalBranch
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your origin and upstream info is like below

```
   $ git remote -v
   origin  git@github.com:<yourname>/<repo_name>.git (fetch)
   origin  git@github.com:<yourname>/<repo_name>.git (push)
   upstream   git@github.com:<repo_owner>/<repo_name>.git (fetch)
   upstream   git@github.com:<repo_owner>/<repo_name>.git (push)
```

and your branch name is like

```
   <repo_owner>:<BranchName>
```

then

```
   git pull origin <BranchName>
```

shall do the job

Comment: When you shared code, please try to explain your code

Answer (score 1):

To checkout PR and **see all changes from that PR** as compared to the main branch in VSCode. Similar to `files changed` section of Github PR page.

1. checkout PR (100) in 'detached HEAD' state
   `git fetch origin pull/100/head && git checkout FETCH_HEAD`
2. show as uncommitted changes
   `git reset main`
3. switch back to main branch and carry these changes
   `git switch -`

Answer (score -2):

There is an easy way for doing this using git-cli

```
gh pr checkout {<number> | <url> | <branch>}
```

Reference: https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_checkout

Comment: How is this answer different from bagerard's?

Answer (score -2):

Create a local branch

```
git checkout -b local-branch-name
```

Pull the remote PR

```
git pull git@github.com:your-repo-ssh.git remote-branch-name
```