# How do I checkout a PR from a fork?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I'm using GitHub to host some projects and someone forked my repo and submitted a PR. I have never had to test a PR in a fork before. How can I checkout the branch and test it? Can I some how pull it into my repo? Or do I checkout the fork and test the branch that way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check out a GitHub pull request with git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567846/how-can-i-check-out-a-github-pull-request-with-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple different ways but I’ll go over what I would do in this situation

`git remote add <whatever you want the remote to be called> <link to the fork>`

[Here is the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote). This will allow you to add and check out the remote branch from the fork. When reviewing PRs in the workflow you described I usually do a `git clean -dfx` (warning: this is a *very* intensive clean that gets rid of unstaged work you have), `git remote add <whatever you want the remote to be called> <link to the fork>`, and `git checkout <branch name>`.

If it’s in your repo already you can see that with `git branch -a` and simply check it out as you might otherwise.

Comment: why suggesting `git clean -dxf`? it is a **very** strong "cleanup feature", and it seems independent of the use case here − the two commands required would just be `git remote add remote-name URL` and `git checkout -b new-local-branch-name -t remote-name/remote-branch-name`

Comment: When peer reviewing on a fork it is frequently necessary to clean the entire environment. The larger the project and build system the more risk there is for leftover files causing false positives. If you don’t do an aggressive clean before compiling checkout out code it’s not unheard of for compiler errors to not be shown or even for code that shouldn’t compile to compile. In a system where pull requests are required to be accurate a ```git clean -dfx``` can be the difference between having to roll back your main branch later in the day or not having to.

Answer (score 18):

You don't need access to the fork.  Just fetch it from the main repo using the PR ref.  If this is PR `3`, then fetch `pull/3/head` like this:

```sh
git fetch origin pull/3/head:my_new_branch
git checkout my_new_branch
```

Answer (score 12):

Basically the "upstream" GitHub repository provides direct access to the forks' PR branches (in read-only) so that you can fetch a given PR and test the corresponding code [after specifying the appropriate ref, `pull/ID/head`](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally).

To this aim, I often use the following alias (which can be used for both *initial fetch*, then *subsequent fetches* if the PR has been updated−thereby overwriting the `pr/ID` local branch):

```
$ git pr
Usage: git pr <id> [<remote>]  # assuming <remote>[=origin] is on GitHub

$ git pr 101  # fetch PR #101 from origin -> branch pr/101

$ git pr 101 upstream # fetch PR #101 from upstream -> branch pr/101
```

> Disclaimer: this definition is not the very last version of the command, see `Further automation` below.

Here is the one-liner definition, then an expanded form:

```
$ git config --global alias.pr '!f() { if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then echo "Usage: git pr <id> [<remote>]  # assuming <remote>[=origin] is on GitHub"; else git checkout -q "$(git rev-parse --verify HEAD)" && git fetch -fv "${2:-origin}" pull/"$1"/head:pr/"$1" && git checkout pr/"$1"; fi; }; f'

# git config --global alias.pr '!f() { if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
  echo "Usage: git pr <id> [<remote>] # assuming <remote>[=origin] is on GitHub";
  else git checkout -q "$(git rev-parse --verify HEAD)" &&
  git fetch -fv "${2:-origin}" pull/"$1"/head:pr/"$1" &&
  git checkout pr/"$1";
  fi; }; f'
```

Note however that you cannot directly push to these special branches.

If ever you'd like to directly modify the PR (commit+force-push) as a maintainer, you should then add the fork as another `remote`, as suggested by @yes-siz (provided [the PR author authorized such access when opening their PR](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/allowing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork)).

### Further automation

It can be noted that the `git pr` alias above creates a *read-only* branch, because being able to force-push to the branch that is associated with the PR would require to push to a specific branch within the source fork repository (assuming its owner authorized this access, as mentioned previously).

Fortunately, [GitHub's REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#list-pull-requests) allows one to easily retrieve this information (the GitHub source repository as well as the source ref), so that one can automate this by relying on a simple [`curl`](https://curl.se/) call and a few standard Git commands including [`git branch --set-upstream-to`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--ultupstreamgt).

All things put together, we can obtain some handy Bash command:

```
$ git prw

Facility to fetch a read/write branch from a GitHub repo Pull Request.

Usage:
  git prw <ID> [<REMOTE>] [-f]

Example:
  git prw 390 upstream

Summary:
  If the REMOTE argument is omitted, it defaults to "origin".
  REMOTE must point to a GitHub repository.

  This command checkouts the branch named "pr/ID" (if it doesn't exist
  yet, it fetches the source branch for the PR #ID in the REMOTE repo)
  and sets its upstream branch so that one can force-push to the fork
  (using an SSH URL); it reuses (if applicable) an existing remote
  matching that URL, or creates a remote named REMOTE-fork-for-pr-ID.

  Flag -f overwrites the local branch pr/ID even if it already exists.
  In general, it is a good idea to pass flag -f, unless we already ran
  "git pr ID REMOTE" and did commits in the local branch pr/ID.

  It requires curl <https://curl.se/> and (optionally) jq.

See also:
  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62432946/9164010
  - https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally
  - https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/allowing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork
```

I published this [`git-prw` command in my `git-scripts` GitHub repository](https://github.com/erikmd/git-scripts/#git-prw) (given it is not a one-liner script any longer :) and this repository also contains an up-to-date version of the [`git-pr`](https://github.com/erikmd/git-scripts/#git-pr) command.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using GitHub, my preferred way to do this is using the official GitHub CLI.

https://github.com/cli/cli

Using the GitHub CLI, you can execute

```
gh pr checkout 101
```

to checkout pr #101

There's also a lot of other useful commands regarding pull requests in the CLI.

Answer (score 4):

My scenario (close if not identical to yours) is maintaining a Github repo which others have forked, and submit PRs.  Here's my process for reviewing forked PRs:

```
git remote add <forked-repo-org-or-name> <forked-repo-github-url>
```

Check the remote was added:

```
git remote -v
```

Fetch the forked repo for latest updates:

```
git fetch <forked-repo-org-or-name>
```

Checkout the forked PR branch:

```
git checkout <name-of-pr-branch>
```

Now you can locally test the branch, explore, and decide whether to merge, comment, etc.

Answer (score 2):

GitHub includes instructions in the pull request for doing this from the command line:
[image: Screenshot of GitHub PR showing link to view command line instructions]

Clicking the "command line instructions" link shows the following:

```
git checkout -b [new-local-branch-name] main
git pull git@github.com:[remote]/[forked-repo].git [the-original/forked-branch-name]
```

Answer (score 0):

The PR is in *your* repo. That's the whole point of the fork-and-PR architecture.

So just `git fetch` and take a look however you like on your machine.

But when the time comes to *merge*, then yes, you will pull the branch from the fork. Fortunately you can have GitHub do that for you.

Comment: Very nice summary here: https://gist.github.com/Chaser324/ce0505fbed06b947d962

Answer (score 0):

Specific answer for clean CI machine minimal checkouts that can work for Github PRs with a source branch from forks or not.

First, some environment variables for clarity:

```markdown
# This is likely provided by the CI provider. Just the normal clone URL.
GIT_HTTP_URL = "git@github.com:organization/repo.git"
# This is the pull request number. Example: https://github.com/organization/repo/pull/14726
PULL_REQUEST_ID = 14726
```

Command to run for sparse checkout of PR:

```sh
$ git init
$ git remote add origin $GIT_HTTP_URL
$ git fetch --jobs=10 --no-tags --depth=1 origin "refs/pull/$PULL_REQUEST_ID/head:pull/$PULL_REQUEST_ID"
$ git checkout "pull/$PULL_REQUEST_ID"
```

This takes the PR checkout time (for my fairly large example repo) from ~1 minute to ~10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

### For Bitbucket

You need to replace the word `pull` with `pull-requests`.

First, you can display the name of the pull request in progress thanks to:

```
$ git ls-remote origin
037edad0925814a92b60a48ee3e36bf64e1df118        refs/heads/pylint
9f27ad743908b25ef3ddfbf8eb95db7de898eb37        refs/pull-requests/1/from
```

As you can see, it is `refs/pull-requests/1/from:my_new_branch` instead of `refs/pull/1/from:my_new_branch`