# How do I graft/transplant a remote branch in git?

Tags: git, github

I have forked a repo in GitHub, and cloned it to my hard disk.

Now someone else had forked the same repo, made some changes in his branch, let's say the name of the branch is "new_features".

That branch does not exist in the origin repo. And neither does it exist on my fork nor on the cloned repo.

How do I pull/graft/transplant that "new_features" branch into my repo?

Comment: @matt as I explicitly mentioned, that "someone else" forked the same origin repo. So it's not unrelated. That person already put in a PR to the origin repo, but they had abandoned their PR and so the changes languished behind the origin repo. I want to pick up the "new_features" branch, merge changes from origin, and submit a new PR.

Comment: I don't see the "new_features" branch on upstream, though. That's why I thought I need to pull/graft the "new_features" branch from "someone else"

Comment: Nevermind, I found out that I have to [do some incantations to pull PRs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30584951/149900); they don't automagically appear in GitHub's UI.

Comment: Also, voted my own question for a close, marking it as a duplicate.

Comment: Well done on both!