# Git - show changes from an unmerged pull request as uncommitted changes in my head branch

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I own the repo. A person sent a PR which I haven't merged yet. I want to see all changes from that PR as compared to my `master` branch in VSCode. It's similar to when you make some changes and those are in uncommitted state). How do I do it?

I followed [How can I check out a GitHub pull request with git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567846/how-can-i-check-out-a-github-pull-request-with-git) but didn't find the answer as per my need. For instance command `git pull origin pull/939/head` will merge the changes instead of showing as uncommitted changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working.

So, my complete flow is:

1. checkout PR (100) in 'detached HEAD' state
   `git fetch origin pull/100/head && git checkout FETCH_HEAD`
2. show as uncommitted changes
   `git reset main`
3. switch back to main branch and carry these changes
   `git switch -`

---

Also, made a handy powershell function

```sh
<# USE CASE
> gitpr
gives list of active PRs

> gitpr 12
checks out PR #12
#>
function gitpr {
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)]
    [String[]] $prNum
  )
  
  if($prNum){
  git fetch origin pull/"$prNum"/head && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
  git reset main 
  git switch -
  echo "checked out PR: "$prNum""
  }else{
  gh pr list
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you must fetch the PR
`git fetch origin pull/<pr_id>/head:new_branch`
now you have the PR changes in `new_branch`
`git diff new_branch ^HEAD | git apply -`

- `git diff <another-branch> ^HEAD` this will print a diff of the changes between the `new_branch` and your current branch (HEAD).
- `git apply -` then this will apply those changes to the current index.

Comment: can I directly see changes in main branch without creating any temporary branch?