# Pulling another dev's PR to my local machine

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch, pull

A dev on my team made a PR to merge his changes from his branch to our "develop" branch.

I want to run his changes to our code on my machine, since I have to write tests for his changes, but I don't get how to do that.

I currently have the "develop" branch for the repo "webapp" on my local machine. When I run `git branch` it shows up as `* develop`.

How do I pull his branch to my local machine so I can run the tests?

Comment: Are they working from a fork? If it's the same repo, you can just pull then checkout their branch same as any other. Or see https://stackoverflow.com/q/27567846/3001761.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pull the changes into your branch (commit them):  `git pull origin pull/939/head` (Note: 939 should be substituted for the PR number)

If you want to pull the changes into a new branch (because you may be working on some other changes in the same service you don't want to override):

`git fetch origin pull/939/head:develop` (Note: 939 is the PR number)

`git checkout myNewBranch`  (Note: myNewBranch is the new branch name you will give for his work you are running on your machine)